# Is my mocking for the EntitySet wrong?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, moq, mstest, entityset

I'm an experienced programmer, but new to LINQ/Moq/Ninject/MVC/MS Test/etc and have run into an issue I haven't been able to figure out.

I have built the SportsStore sample from the Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework book (but with .NET 4.5/MVC 4). I got that working and now I've begun to convert it to work with our real database. The main difference at this point is that we do not only have a Product class, but also a ProductSub class. Each Product class consists of 1 or more ProductSub's and I have defined this with an EntitySet Association. To make the CartController to know which ProductSub to add to the Cart I decided to change CartController.AddToCart to take a productSubId instead of a productId.

Everything seems to work fine when I run the website and manually click "add product". However, when I run my unit tests I get a NullReferenceException because cart.Lines[0] is null. I don't think the error is in CartController since that seems to work when I run the webpage, and I tried to use the FakeProductsRepository (modified to add ProductSubID's) to rule out Moq causing this (which didn't help, so I don't think the error has anything to do with Moq).

I've figured out that this line in CartController returns null in the unit test but not when I run the webpage:

```
productsRepository.ProductSubs.FirstOrDefault(ps => ps.ProductSubID == productSubId);
```

So I tried to hard code the CartController to see if LINQ to the Product instead would work, which it did! I think that means that the productsRepository have Product's, but that for some reason the Product's doesn't have a ProductSub's. I'm I right so far?

My best guess is that there's something wrong with this code in the unit test:

```
new Product { ProductID = 2, ProductSubs = new List<ProductSub> { new ProductSub { ProductSubID = 456} } }
```

But I can't figure out what. Is it wrong to use List? I tried using EntitySet instead but it made got the same error.

Unit test code:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Can_Add_Product_To_Cart()
    {
        // Arrange: Give a repository with some products...
        var mockProductsRepository = UnitTestHelpers.MockProductsRepository(
            new Product { ProductID = 1, ProductSubs = new List<ProductSub> { new ProductSub { ProductSubID = 123 } } },
            new Product { ProductID = 2, ProductSubs = new List<ProductSub> { new ProductSub { ProductSubID = 456 } } }
        );

        var cartController = new CartController(mockProductsRepository, null);
        var cart = new Cart();

        // Act: When a user adds a product to their cart...
        cartController.AddToCart(cart, 456, null);

        // Assert: Then the product is in their cart
        Assert.AreEqual(1, cart.Lines.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(456, cart.Lines[0].ProductSub.ProductSubID);
    }
```

Cart class:

```
public class Cart
{
    private List<CartLine> lines = new List<CartLine>();
    public IList<CartLine> Lines { get { return lines.AsReadOnly(); } }

    public void AddItem(ProductSub productSub, int quantity)
    {
        var line = lines.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductSub.ProductSubID == productSub.ProductSubID);
        if (line == null)
            lines.Add(new CartLine { ProductSub = productSub, Quantity = quantity });
        else
            line.Quantity += quantity;
    }

    public decimal ComputeTotalValue()
    {
        return lines.Sum(l => (decimal)l.ProductSub.Price * l.Quantity);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        lines.Clear();
    }

    public void RemoveLine(ProductSub productSub)
    {
        lines.RemoveAll(l => l.ProductSub.ProductSubID == productSub.ProductSubID);
    }
}

public class CartLine
{
    public ProductSub ProductSub { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Product class:

```
[Table]
public class Product
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Column(Name = "id", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a product name")]
    [Column]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a description")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Column(Name = "info")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public float LowestPrice 
    {
        get { return (from product in ProductSubs select product.Price).Min(); }
    }

    private EntitySet<ProductSub> _ProductSubs = new EntitySet<ProductSub>();
    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Association(Storage = "_ProductSubs", OtherKey = "ProductID")]
    public ICollection<ProductSub> ProductSubs
    {
        get { return _ProductSubs; }
        set { _ProductSubs.Assign(value); }
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please specify a category")]
    [Column]
    public string Category { get; set; }
}

[Table]
public class ProductSub
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Column(Name = "id", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int ProductSubID { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "products_id")]
    private int ProductID;
    private EntityRef<Product> _Product = new EntityRef<Product>();
    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Association(Storage = "_Product", ThisKey = "ProductID")]
    public Product Product
    {
        get { return _Product.Entity; }
        set { _Product.Entity = value; }
    }

    [Column]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0.00, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a positive price")]
    [Column]
    public float Price { get; set; }
}
```

UnitTestHelpers code (which should be fine since I tried the FakeProductsRepository):

```
    public static IProductsRepository MockProductsRepository(params Product[] products)
    {
        var mockProductsRepos = new Mock<IProductsRepository>();
        mockProductsRepos.Setup(x => x.Products).Returns(products.AsQueryable());
        return mockProductsRepos.Object;
    }
```

CartController code (which should be fine since it works on the webpage):

```
    public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(Cart cart, int productSubId, string returnUrl)
    {
        //Product product = productsRepository.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == 2);
        //cart.AddItem(product.ProductSubs.FirstOrDefault(), 1);
        ProductSub productSub = productsRepository.ProductSubs.FirstOrDefault(ps => ps.ProductSubID == productSubId);
        cart.AddItem(productSub, 1);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
    }
```

Code for FakeProductsRepository:

```
public class FakeProductsRepository : IProductsRepository
{
    private static IQueryable<Product> fakeProducts = new List<Product> {
        new Product { Name = "Football", ProductSubs = new List<ProductSub> { new ProductSub { ProductSubID = 123, Price = 25 } } },
        new Product { Name = "Surf board", ProductSubs = new List<ProductSub> { new ProductSub { ProductSubID = 456, Price = 179 } } },
        new Product { Name = "Running shoes", ProductSubs = new List<ProductSub> { new ProductSub { ProductSubID = 789, Price = 95 } } }
    }.AsQueryable();

    public FakeProductsRepository(params Product[] prods)
    {
        fakeProducts = new List<Product>(prods).AsQueryable();
    }

    public IQueryable<Product> Products
    {
        get { return fakeProducts; }
    }

    public IQueryable<ProductSub> ProductSubs
    {
        get { return fakeProducts.SelectMany(ps => ps.ProductSubs); }
    }

    public void SaveProduct(Product product)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void DeleteProduct(Product product)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution thanks to Martin Liversage. The mock WAS wrong, but I didn't figure it out because my FakeProductsRepository was ALSO wrong. Due to the dependency between Products and ProductSubs I don't think his suggested change to the mock would work though (but please correct me if I'm wrong).

The issue in FakeProductsRepository was that the constructor overwrote the initial fakeProducts collection with an empty collection. Once I changed that to only overwrite the initial collection if a new collection was supplied as parameter the unit tests worked using the FakeProductsRepository.

```
    public FakeProductsRepository(params Product[] products)
    {
        if (products != null)
            fakeProducts = new List<Product>(products).AsQueryable();
    }
```

Thus there was an issue with the mock since that still didn't work. To solve it all I needed to do was to remove the ProductSubs function from IProductsRepository (which I had intended as a shortcut, but which I realized messed up the mocking). Once I did that and accessed the ProductSubs through the Products in CartController everything worked again.

```
    public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(Cart cart, int productSubId, string returnUrl)
    {
        ProductSub productSub = productsRepository.Products.SelectMany(p => p.ProductSubs).FirstOrDefault(ps => ps.ProductSubID == productSubId);
        cart.AddItem(productSub, 1);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
    }
```

That was all I needed, but to simplify the test code I also decided to use pure ProductSub objects where that was enough instead of accessing them through a Product. Where I needed the whole Product (ie when the IProductsRepository was involved I used this code which I think is cleaner then creating the whole object on one line (ie with new List etc):

```
var ps1 = new ProductSub { ProductSubID = 11 };
var p1 = new Product();
p1.ProductSubs.Add(ps1);
```

Comment: If your problem is that `cart.Lines[0]` is null my answer solves your problem and my explanation should make it obvious what is going on. I even tested the code to make sure I didn't make any syntactic mistakes. However, all the edits and additional code snippets makes me less certain that I have provided you with an adequate answer about how to fix your mock. Before you modified the code the root cause of your problem was that you didn't mock `IProductsRepository.ProductSubs`.

Comment: I've came to realize that. However I did supply the ProductSub's through the List added to Product, but I think the issue was that Moq couldn't know what to return without telling it somehow. Your solution might work, but it felt easier to remove that function and always go through `IProductsRepository.Products`.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you have provided a lot of code some necessary information is missing so I'm assuming that `IProductsRepository.ProductSubs` returns `IQueryable<ProductSub>`. The `MockProductsRepository` method creates a mock for `IProductsRepository` but does not do any setup for `IProductsRepository.ProductSubs`. The mocking framework will most likely return an empty `IQueryable<ProductSub>`.

In the `AddToCart` you try to find the `ProductSub` using `productsRepository.ProductSubs.FirstOrDefault`. Because the mock returns an empty collection `FirstOrDefault` will return null thus you call `cart.AddItem(null, 1)` which explains why `cart.Lines[0]` is null.

Before fixing the mock you could consider doing parameter validation, e.g.

```
public void AddItem(ProductSub productSub, int quantity) 
{ 
    if (productSub == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("productSub");
    if (quantity < 1)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("quantity");
```

Then when you rerun your test it will be much clearer where your problem is.

Next thing will then be to create a setup for `IProductsRepository.ProductSubs` in `MockProductsRepository`:

```
mockProductsRepos
  .Setup(x => x.ProductSubs)
  .Returns(products.SelectMany(p => p.ProductSubs).AsQueryable());
```

This simply creates a collection of all the `ProductSub` objects from the `Product` objects provided to `MockProductsRepository`. You can of course modify this as you see fit.

Comment: Sorry, it should be cart.Lines[0] which is null. I've edited my original question and also added the Cart class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your assumptions are correct, and your answer looks promising. Does that mean that my code for FakeProductsRepository is wrong? I'll add it to my original question in a minute.

Comment: I tried to remove the ProductsSub function from IProductsRepository change the line in CartController to this: ProductSub productSub = productsRepository.Products.SelectMany(ps => ps.ProductSubs).FirstOrDefault(ps => ps.ProductSubID == productSubId);

It still works when I run the webpage, but not in the unit test. I also added your validation code and productSub is null.

Comment: The purpose of removing IProductsRepository.ProductSubs was that I was thinking it might confuse Moq, but that doesn't seem to be the case since it's not working even after removing it.

Perhaps the error is in this code even though it works on the real page:
`ProductSub productSub = productsRepository.Products.SelectMany(ps => ps.ProductSubs).FirstOrDefault(ps => ps.ProductSubID == productSubId)`

Comment: I don't think you can confuse Moq. However, I get somewhat confused by all this code, in particular `FakeRepository`. Do you want to use the Moq framework or do you want to write your own mock? Anyway, the solution is simple. You need to stub/mock/create a setup for `IProductsRepository.ProductSubs` so it doesn't return an empty collection as stated in my answer (and now with actual code on how to do that with Moq).

Comment: I've noticed my FakeProductsRepository IS wrong. The problem was that the constructor overwrote the default list of products. When commenting out this line it works with FakeProductsRepository:

`fakeProducts = new List<Product>(prods).AsQueryable();`

Comment: If I understand the book correctly FakeProductsRepository is only used as an example of manual mocking before the book introduces Moq. I only tried it to rule out issues with Moq, but failed because FakeProductsRepository didn't do what I thought it did.

As for your suggested solution I'm not sure if it would work because of the dependency between Product's and ProductSub's. However I didn't really need IProductsRepository.ProductSubs so I removed it which solved the issue.